# Using C++ library in iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone

[image: The screen shot is the crash report when I try to call C++ method]I've a task in which I need to use a .a c++ library (don't have any idea what is the code in that library) with a header file having some methods declared in it. Now what I need to do is to call these methods from my objective c class. for this I've done following things:

1. changed the extension of my view controller class from .m to .mm
2. set my 'other C++ flags' in build settings to objective-c++

all other steps which were suggested at stack overflow and any where else.still I'm not able to use that library. An example will give you all the better understanding on my problem:

suppose We've a library mylibrary.a,We also have a header file named myHeaderFile.h. Now we need to call a method named 'int Login(unsigned long *LoginInfo)' which is declared in myHeaderFile.h header file. What should be done? The screen shot is the crash report when I try to call C++ method

What can be mistake here,please suggest. A quick help will be appreciated...

Comment: `still I'm not able to use that library` What is your actual problem? Any error?

Comment: app crashes without any error message. Here what I'm trying to do is to use a C++ library in my objective c app but don't have any idea where to go and what to do?

Comment: Does the app crash when call the c++ function, or just on load?

Comment: exactly, when I call c++ function.

Comment: "we need to call a method named" - it's a class method or a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach to the app with any debugger or turn on Error Reporting to see what exactly crashes.

**UPD:** Apple's [LLDB tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/gdb_to_lldb_transition_guide/document/lldb-terminal-workflow-tutorial.html). You need these steps:

1. **Specifying the Program to Debug**
2. **Launching the Program with LLDB** (<kbd>r</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Finally, when it crashes, type <kbd>bt</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I've added the screen shot of the crash report..suggest me if you find any thing.

Comment: Do you call this function - `IOTC_Connect()`? If yes, make sure you pass `char *` to it. If no, let's go deeper: attach `gdb` or `lldb` to the app, run it, and when it crashes - type `bt` (backtrace), we'll see the call stack.

Comment: Bam!!! It helped me,I found that there was an error in library or in other words,the library was corrupted so I just changed the library and now every thing is fine..